# ASP.NET MVC Core: Error occurs after adding IdentityUser

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm learning to build a ASP.NET MVC Core web application. Everything works fine until I start to add `Identity` to it.

Registered **User** can create many **Jobs**. I use the `ApplicationUser.cs` that comes with the project for the **User**. I created another `DbContext` for all others entities.

`ApplicationUser.cs` in Model:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    // CUSTOM PROPERTIES
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Job> Jobs { get; set; }
}
```

`Job.cs` in Model:

```
public class Job 
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }

    // contains other properties

    public string ApplicationUserID { get; set; }
    public virtual ApplicationUser ApplicationUser { get; set; }
}
```

`ApplicationDbContext.cs`:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options) : base(options)
    {

    }
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);
    }
}
```

**When I add these 2 lines in `Job.cs`, the error pops up.**

```
    public string ApplicationUserID { get; set; }
    public virtual ApplicationUser ApplicationUser { get; set; }
```

> **Error ==>>**
>
> Unhandled Exception: System.Exception: Could not resolve a service of
>   type 'MyProject.Data.JobDbContext' for the parameter 'context' of
>   method 'Configure' on type 'MyProject.Startup'. --->
>   System.InvalidOperationException: The entity type
>   'IdentityUserLogin' requires a primary key to be defined.

I know that there are some threads discussing about the same error, but those answer can't really help.

Comment: Some post says adding `base.OnModelCreating` statement to `OnModelCreating` method could solve the problem but it doesn't in my code.

Comment: reading the error i think you've not a PK in your User model ..could be?

Comment: I can't see the mappings for tables..... did you do these mappings?

Comment: @federicoscamuzzi The `ApplicantionUser` model is derived from `IdentityUser`. Isn't it got the `UserId` PK inherited from `IdentityUser`? I tried to add `public int ApplicationUserId { get; set; }` to the `ApplicationUser` but still showing the same problem...

Comment: @federico-scamuzzi, IdenityUser already has the PK, but the lack of mappings can affect the model

Comment: @Lari, in term of mapping, do you mean a list of `DbSet<>` in the `DbContext`?

Comment: No, @Matt, I mean the mapping definition. Are you using Fluent Mapping or only rely on conventions?

Comment: I always declare the ICollection<T> with virtual as well. Just a note. ;)

Comment: @Lari, No I didn't. I just rely on convention. Could it be a matter of this error?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131783/discussion-between-lari-and-matt).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is two different contexts.

`JobDbContext` contains `Job`, which refers to `ApplicationUser` which is NOT in this context, but added by EF automatically because you linked to it. And this `ApplicationUser` (it's parent `IdentityUser`) contains collection of logins (`IdentityUserLogin`) which is not part of this context too, but auto-added by EF, and so on... All this classes are configured in `OnModelCreating` of `IdentityDbContext` and NOT configured in `JobDbContext` that's why you see this error - you have no description keys/indexes/references of this classes in `JobDbContext`.

You should either combine two DbContext into one, or remove `public virtual ApplicationUser ApplicationUser { get; set; }` from `Job` class and manage related object manually (ensure referential integrity, do lazy loading etc).

Comment: It really makes sense! When I combine two `DbContext` into one, it works like a charm. But I really want to learn more how to manage this with two different contexts - I don't really get what you mean "manage related object manually". Could you show me some example please? As I read through some online tutorials, they usually leave `ApplicationDbContext` alone and create their own `DbContext`. Instead of one `DbContext` for all, it seems that having separate `DbContext` handling different part of entities is more neatly or separation of concern.

Comment: Imagine that two different dbcontexts may be two different physical databases, even on different DB engines. It's how EF "think" about them. All "links" between them (`Job` in one and `User` in other) exists only inside your app. EF known nothing about cross-dbcontext operation. If your app should "do not delete user if he owns at least one job" - you should write this code yourself. If you need to show list of jobs with user names - you should read jobs into `List` from first dbcontext, read users from other dbcontext and merge/join this lists "manually" in memory.