# Error on running migration in MVC Core application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to run the following command to create a new migration for a context that I created myself. I run this command.

```
dotnet ef migrations add MusicContextCreation --context MusicContext
```

Here is my music context class. This is what I'm trying to add a migration for.

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace MusicianProject.Models.Contexts
{
    public class MusicContext : DbContext
    {
        public MusicContext(DbContextOptions<MusicContext> options) : base(options)
        {

        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(builder);

            //builder.Entity<Band>().HasMany<BandMember>();
            //builder.Entity<Band>().HasMany<Album>(band => band.Albums);
            builder.Entity<Band>().ToTable("Band");
            //builder.Entity<BandMember>().HasOne<User>(bandmember => bandmember.User);
            builder.Entity<BandMember>().ToTable("BandMember");
            builder.Entity<Album>().ToTable("Album");
            builder.Entity<Genre>().ToTable("Genre");
        }

        public DbSet<Band> Bands { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Genre> Genres { get; set; }
        public DbSet<BandMember> BandMembers { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Album> Albums { get; set; }

    }
}
```

Here is the error message I'm getting in the command prompt when I run that command.

> The entity type Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore.IdentityUserLogin requires a primary key to be defined.

What I don't understand is I have called the base classes OnModelCreating which I've seen as the answer in other similar questions. What I don't understand is that another context I have for Identity users, does not give me this issue, and it actually sets up the identity tables.

I can add the classes that are being used in this context if need be, I did not add them yet as I didn't want to clutter. Let me know in the comments if it is needed to see the classes being defined in dbset collections.

Answer (score 1):

You should inherit from `IdentityDbContext` (instead of `DbContext`), which has proper `OnModelCreating` content with fluent configuration of Identity classes.

If you want to have two different DbContexts, one for users and other for other classes - you should not have any references between classes in different contexts, read [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41381188/460298)

Comment: I changed the class to inherit from IdentityDbContext and I still get the same error. Are you suggesting that I move the DbSets to my IdentityDbContext? I don't get why they have to be separate.

Comment: What you mean "my IdentityDbContext"? You should inherit from one in `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFramework` namespace, see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/identity#configure-identity-and-membership)

Comment: Sorry, I meant my "UserContext" Class. I changed my MusicContext to inherit from IdentityDbContext, and it still wouldn't work. So I commented out the Band and Band Member sets, and it worked (I assume this is because they had reference to my User class which inherits from IdentityUser).

Comment: This cleanly shows that you have something wrong in inheriting users and other Identity classes, because when you remove all references to them (commenting `Band` and `BandMember`) - your `DbContext` works. It's hard to says what is exactly wrong without seeing all code involved.